# How to make tracking single page applications with Matomo

Tags: single-page-application, matomo

Matomo (web analytics tool) tracking of a Single Page Application is a little bit more difficult than to track a server side rendered page which is everytime reloaded if we navigate to another page.

There is a tutorial by Matomo:
https://developer.matomo.org/guides/spa-tracking

But the 'hashchange' event fires not on every SPA.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution. I could not use `'hashchange'` event, because my SPA doesn't use hashes on URLs, so `'hashchange'` doesn't fire. Thus use 'click' event:

```
<!-- Matomo -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
    
    // default tracking (if the page reload completely)
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);

    (function() {
      var u="https://MATOMO-INSTANCE-DOMAIN";
      _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
      _paq.push(['setSiteId', '17']);
      var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();

    // ONLY for the SPA because the page doesn't reload on navigation to other pages
    document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      const clickedUrl = event.originalTarget.href;
      // if a NAVIGATION link (menu item in the SPA) was clicked
      if(clickedUrl) {
        _paq.push(['setCustomUrl', clickedUrl]);
        _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
        _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
      }
    });
  </script>
  <noscript><p><img src="https://MATOMO-INSTANCE-DOMAIN/matomo.php?idsite=17&amp;rec=1" style="border:0;" alt="" /></p></noscript>
  <!-- End Matomo Code -->
```